# how to run mbpipe... a program I just installed

Tags: node.js, npm, mbtiles

I'm trying to use this tool: https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles/wiki/Post-processing-MBTiles-with-MBPipe

I've installed mbtiles with `npm install -g mbtiles`.  I've also installed it locally (in the dir I'm working in) with just plain `npm install mbtiles`.

That part worked (I was able to download the files), but now according to the readme I can just start entering in commands like

`mbpipe 'pngquant 64' myMbTilesFile.mbtiles`  and it's supposed to work?

Umm... don't I have to run a specific script file (like "node scriptfile.js")?  This is acting like I can call functions within a script and pass it variables?  I can tell you, as the user mentioned, that 'mbpipe' is within the utils.js file I have.... but how am I supposed to use it?

when I enter in the above command, I of course get "mbpipe: command not found"

So... what are they talking about?

Comment: Looks like it has been removed for some reason - https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles/issues/31

Comment: OMG thankyou for pointing that out.  I was going crazy